# Swift capture video to different paths

Tags: swift, swift3, avfoundation, avcapturesession

I'm trying to capture a video using swift. I want to capture the video in a new file every x seconds.

Here is my current code:

```
var i = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if setupSession() {
        setupPreview()
        startSession()
    }

}

func setupSession() -> Bool {

    ...

    return true
}

func startSession() {

    ...
}

func tempURL() -> URL? {
    let directory = NSTemporaryDirectory() as NSString

    if directory != "" {

        i = i+1
        old_cur_videoID = cur_videoID_system

        cur_videoID_system = "\(cur_videoID)_\(i).mp4"
        let path = directory.appendingPathComponent(cur_videoID_system)
        return URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    }

    return nil
}


func startRecording() {


    let delayTime = DispatchTime.now() + 2
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: delayTime) {
        self.startRecording()
    }

    outputURL = tempURL()
    movieOutput.startRecording(toOutputFileURL: outputURL, recordingDelegate: self)
}
```

And the two delegate functions:

```
func capture(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didStartRecordingToOutputFileAt fileURL: URL!, fromConnections connections: [Any]!) {

}

func capture(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAt outputFileURL: URL!, fromConnections connections: [Any]!, error: Error!) {
    if (error != nil) {
        print("Error recording movie: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
    } else {        
        if(i > 1){
            saveOnServer()
        }   
    }
    outputURL = nil
}
```

If I try to run the Code, I get the following Error-Message:

```
Error recording movie: Movie recording cannot be started
```

Can somebody help me with my problem? If more code is necessary or some parts are unclear, please feel free to ask.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please simplify your code to only include the relevant parts.

Comment: Sorry for that. I hope it's looks better now.

Comment: Does code create any files successfully? Don't your file names end up with multiple ".mp4" suffixes?

Comment: I dont see you stopping the recording anywhere?

Comment: A file ist not getting created...

Comment: Correct, I don't stop the recording. The reason is that I want to continue recording to another file. I've read in the Apple Documentary that I don't have to stop the recording. I just have to call movieOutput.startRecording to another file.